# Query generates an error

Tags: java, android

I am doing the request, it writes an error
id - INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
help

```
cur = db.query("Sales_region_table t1, region_table t2  join region_table t2 on t1.id_region = t2.id ", null, " id_region = " + id_region + " and id_category = " + id_category + " and id_product = " + id_product + " ", null, null, null, null);
```

11-01 08:28:10.600: I/Database(1251): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = ambiguous column name: t2.id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is around:

```
region_table t2  join region_table t2
```

You're selecting from `region_table t2` and joining to the same table (with the same alias name).

This causes ambiguity on the RDBMS.

Comment: I don't know your requirement. What do you want to achieve?